# Match names to cohort in time-series

Tags: r, merge, match, group

I have a data frame with a list of identifiers (names_ex). I then have a list of identifiers matched with cohorts at a particular point in time (cohort_list). My goal is to see a time-series of the cohort each identifier belongs to.

In practice, I have a ncol(names_ex) = 2000 names and length(cohort_list) = 200.

This question is not a duplicate of: [Simultaneously merge multiple data.frames in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091303/simultaneously-merge-multiple-data-frames-in-a-list)

The names_ex vector makes it quite different. Also in practice I have many more elements in cohort_list, and I can't manually combine them 1 by 1

```
names_ex <- as.data.frame(c("AB1", "AB2", "AB3", "AB4", "AB5", "AB6", "AB7", "AB8", "AB9", "AB10"))

match1 <- as.data.frame(rbind(c("AB1",1),
                c("AB9",2),
                c("AB8",3),
                c("AB2",1)))

match2 <- as.data.frame(rbind(c("AB3",2),
                c("AB4",4),
                c("AB6",4),
                c("AB7",3)))

match3 <- as.data.frame(rbind(c("AB9",1),
                c("AB8",1),
                c("AB2",1),
                c("AB6",3),
                c("AB10",1)))

colnames(match1) <- c("Name", "Cohort")
colnames(match2) <- c("Name", "Cohort")
colnames(match3) <- c("Name", "Cohort")
cohort_list <- list(match1,match2,match3)


output <- cbind.data.frame(c("AB1", "AB2", "AB3", "AB4", "AB5", "AB6", "AB7", "AB8", "AB9", "AB10"),
                c(1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3, 2, NA),
                c(NA, NA, 2,4, NA, 4, 3, NA, NA, NA),
                c(NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 3, NA, 1, 1, 1))
```

Comment: Hello Jak, your question looks like a duplicate of what Ritchie closed it as. Please [edit] your question to provide more clear output that will help us differentiate your question.